# Replace just one instance of a character not every single occurrence

Tags: python

I am working on a code that replaces the symbol in the code which happens to be a patterned message where every single non-space is a "*".

However, my code replaces c, but instead of just replacing c in the code it replaces all instances of c not just the c in the index order of the patterned message.

```
for c in pattern:
        if c == ("*"):
            i += 1
            pattern = 
pattern.replace(c,msg[(i%letters)])
    print(pattern)

so it returns 
    T     T     T
   TTT   TTT   TTT
  TTTTT TTTTT TTTTT
   TTT   TTT   TTT
    T     T     T,
not T     h     r
   eeD   iam   ond
  s!Th   reeD iamo
  dsT   hre   Dia
   m    o     n
```

NOTE, i can not use list in my code

Comment: Welcome. You can replace character manually: `pattern[index] = msg[(i%letters)]`. To iterate over string with both values and indexes you can use [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate).

Comment: Can you post the original string?

Comment: Look at the `replace` documentation; simply use the `maxreplace` argument of `1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you are trying to do:

You want the line

```
pattern = pattern.replace(c,msg[(i%letters)])
```

to replace only the first occurrence of c. There is a third optional argument to replace that specifies the maximum replacements (in order)

```
pattern = pattern.replace(c,msg[(i%letters)],1)
```